# Autosizing text in TextView on Android

Tags: android, text, widget, textview

Is it possible to set `TextView`'s text size to be the same as `TextView` height, when TextView height isn't predefined(`WRAP_CONTENT` or `FILL_PARENT`)?

solution : [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

Comment: You mean stretching characters and show them inside TextView? why exactly you want to do this? motivation factor?

Comment: I've got TextView with some text which should take all remaining space of screen

Comment: could you please post your layout xml where textview is residing, thnks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the library that do exactly what I want :  [SizeAdjustingTextView](https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=daf610a283-Android_Weekly_101&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-daf610a283-337844189)

Answer (score 0):

i also wanted to do something like this and the closest you can seem to get is to say `android:textSize=20dp` (or whatever size you think is appropriate) for either your style or each element that is displaying text. since `dp` is device independent pixels, if it appears to be taking up the whole screen on your device, then it is supposed to appear that way on all other devices too. you might want to check on this as you might have to choose a different dp value for each of the different size/density combinations possible (depending on what kind of devices you are aimed at, also whether you are allowing the use to change the orientation) [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has all that info.